# Is it possible inside a controller method to get the currently used MessageConverter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
        "application/json", "application/xml" })
public @ResponseBody List<Foo> getAll(...)
```

I wanna know, inside the controller method, which strategy / converter Spring Mvc will use handling the current Http request (chosing to produce xml OR json).

Is there any method like getCurrentMessageConverter() ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete list of HttpMessageConverters set up by mvc:annotation-driven:

- ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter converts byte arrays.
- StringHttpMessageConverter converts strings.
- ResourceHttpMessageConverter converts to/from org.springframework.core.io.Resource for all media types.
- SourceHttpMessageConverter converts to/from a javax.xml.transform.Source.
- FormHttpMessageConverter converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.

  Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter converts Java objects to/from XML — added if JAXB2 is present and Jackson 2 XML extension is not present on the classpath.

  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converts to/from JSON — added if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath.

  MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converts to/from XML — added if Jackson 2 XML extension is present on the classpath.

  AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter converts Atom feeds — added if Rome is present on the classpath.

  RssChannelHttpMessageConverter converts RSS feeds — added if Rome is present on the classpath.

In your case, Spring uses MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter to convert request to json.

Comment: @gpilotino If you haven't configured it, by default it should be MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: i mean, programmatically (the request can produce xml or json according to spring request handler mapping criteria)

Comment: @gpilotino So you would like to know the type of the request ? Because I can't see why you want to know the type of the convertor.

Comment: yes, i would like to know the type of produced output (if json or xml).  i need it to do some customization to the used objectmapper at runtime

Comment: @gpilotino I'm a bit confused, the produced type is you who decide. Or you mean the consumes type?

Comment: the produced type is what spring decides according to some criteria (http headers, url suffix, and so on). at the end of the decision process spring  choses a messageconverter so i would like to programatically obtain the chosen one inside method controller

Comment: @gpilotino yes, your are right. To determine the type, there are some ways, as you have mentioned, you can look into the header or content-type of the request, also the url suffix. But I have no idea how to get out that in a simple way.